# Why does this explicit template specialization does not work?

Tags: c++, templates

from this code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Z { static const int z = 1; };
struct Y { static const int y = 2; };

template <typename A> struct TE { int foo(); int bar(); };

template <> int TE<Y>::bar() { return foo(); }
template <typename A> int TE<A>::bar() { return foo(); }

template <> int TE<Y>::foo() { return Y::y; }
template <typename A> int TE<A>::foo() { return A::z; }

template struct TE<Z>;
template struct TE<Y>;

int main()
{
    TE<Z> z;
    TE<Y> y;

    std::cout << z.bar() << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.bar() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with this error

```
21:28: error: specialization of 'int TE<A>::foo() [with A = Y]' after instantiation
 In instantiation of 'int TE<A>::foo() [with A = Y]':
13:12:   required from here
28:15: error: 'z' is not a member of 'Y'
 In member function 'int TE<A>::foo() [with A = Y]':
29:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

these implementations are done in separate cpp file. and the structs are in a header, typical explicit template instantiation.

why did this

```
int TE<Y>::bar() { return foo(); }
```

tries to use this

```
template <typename A> int TE<A>::foo() { return A::z; }
```

instead of this

```
template <> int TE<Y>::foo() { return Y::y; }
```

Comment: To add. If I move both TE<A>::foo and TE<Y>::foo above bar implementations, it works just fine.
Did it violate anything on standard?
This has same behavior in Visual Studio and GCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

**Explicit specialization** can only appear in the same namespace as the primary template, and **has to appear after the non-specialized template declaration**.

Also, you need to follow the One-Definition-Rule (ODR). So usually you would provide your implementations along in the same header.

Comment: Ahh, I missed this while reading that documentation

*"Specialization must be declared before the first use that would cause implicit instantiation, in every translation unit where such use occurs:"*

It all makes sense now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `foo` specialization isn't known at the time `bar` is instantiated, so `foo` in *both* `bar`s refers to the `foo` base template.

As the first error message says, when the compiler gets to your `Y` specialization, the base template has already been instantiated, using `A = Y`.
The second error is a "cascade error" due to the specialization failure, in the grand C++ tradition.

If you rearrange the definitions, it works:

```
template <typename A> int TE<A>::foo() { return A::z; }
template <> int TE<Y>::foo() { return Y::y; }

template <typename A> int TE<A>::bar() { return foo(); }
template <> int TE<Y>::bar() { return foo(); }
```

Comment: I also noticed that.
So we should be careful of coding these kind of code then.